# wait for state to change in the same function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I wait for the url hook to not be empty? handleViewSheet is an on click function and I do not want to use useEffect because of the initial render. Can this be done without useEffect?

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

const handleViewSheet = () => {

    GetSheet(id).then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        setUrl(res);
      }
    });

    const task = getDocument(url); // url is still empty at this point

}
```

Comment: I would just set a local variable in the `handleViewSheet` to save `res` and use that to reference it until the `setUrl` updates.

Comment: but the fetch request is still asynchronus meaning even if I set a local variable before it and set that variable to res, it will still run the next line before it ever changes right?

Comment: hmmm... i think it will still work, you can try it and let me know. I'll think of an alternative in the meantime

Comment: If you depend on url update then you need to use useEffect. If you depend only on res you can implement your logic inside at promise or convert your function to async/await

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a job for `useEffect` to be honest, so I would recommand to consider using it (You can handle the first render within the useEffect if you want).

But if you still want to avoid using `useEffect`, you can use `async/await` to wait for the promise to finish before using url, along with the `setUrl` call. Something like this:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState('')

const handleViewSheet = async () => {

    let resUrl = await GetSheet(id).then((res) => {
      if (res) {
        setUrl(res);
        return res;
      }
      return '';
    });

    const task = getDocument(resUrl );

}
```